# Meteor cordova app, access local stored video

Tags: cordova, video, meteor, local-storage

i'm developing a meteor/cordova APP. I try to play offline video stored on device memory and play it in html5 video tag but when i get file local path in format 'file:///' i cannot load it because i have a security access violation.

- I just try to use cordova httpd server but without success because it works on iOS but not well on Android.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my test environment and it works.

- Cordova 5.4.0
- Must Plugin: cordova-plugin-file 3.0.0 "File" (above)

You should use `cdvfile://` instead of `file:///` the relate config please reference the [cdvfile protocol](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#cdvfile-protocol)

Comment: Thanks, it works for images, pdfs, but i cannot play videos... how to you install cordova 5.4.0? What html code you put in HTML? i'm using video tag with <source src="cdvfile://video.mp4">

Comment: @SimoneM, You can use [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) to install cordova. It's a good package manage system